# How do I use jquery for div's onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have several div's on my page. See example http://jsfiddle.net/AYRh6/26/
When I'm trying to transfer this code to my asp.net mvc3 project it looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $('.tab').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        })​;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
        <div class="tab" style="float:right;">Tab 3</div>
        <div class="tab" style="float:right;">Tab 2</div>
        <div class="tab active" style="float:right;">Tab 1</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    width:325px;
}
div.tab {
    background: white;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding-left:5px;
}
div.tab.active {
    background: blue;
}
div.tab:hover {
    background: aqua;
}
```

As you can see javascript is located at the header of html page. It doesn't work for me.
I was trying to set this script for `onclick` event like:

```
<div class="tab" style="float:right;" onclick="$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');">Tab 3</div>
            <div class="tab" style="float:right;" onclick="$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');">Tab 2</div>
            <div class="tab active" style="float:right;" onclick="$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');">Tab 1</div>
```

It's work fine! What I'm doing wrong when this script located at the header?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){PUT YOUR CODE HERE}); or better set it just before the body closing tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javascript code is executed immediately but the elements that you want to attach the handlers to haven't been put into the DOM yet. You can use [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in jQuery or put your script at the bottom of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.tab').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
     })​;
</script>
```

If you use a debugger and set a breakpoint at `$('.tab').click` in your code you'll notice that `$('.tab')` returns an empty array of elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look to your link you will see that you choose the option to execute the script on DOM ready. You have to do the same on your website.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    })​;

});
```